# Pylons redirect to 404 error page

Tags: python, pylons

What function to I use to redirect to the default 404 error page?  Sample code appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abort(404)` as mentioned in the [quickwiki tutorial](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/tutorials/quickwiki_tutorial/). See the docs for [abort](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/modules/controllers_util/#pylons.controllers.util.abort).

Answer (score 0):

404 isn't something you redirect to; there's no distinct "404 page" with its own distinct URL.  It's a status code that you send back in the HTTP response, instead of 200 (the code for a normal successful response).

Actual redirects are also status codes, such as 301 or 307, that can be used instead of 200 or 404.

Read about the [status line in an HTTP response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) for more info.

Comment: This is not true. The server sends back a special 404 error page that developers can customize to their needs. Try entering a non-existing URL at stackoverflow.com, for example.

Comment: @Heikki Toivonen: A 404 response can contain a body with HTML (or anything else) in it, but there's no redirect involved.  A redirect means you ask for one URL, and the server responds with another URL that your browser should load instead.  If you enter a nonexistent URL at stackoverflow.com, and then look in your address bar, you'll find that it hasn't changed.  The server didn't redirect you to the URL of a "page-not-found error message page", it just sent you the "page not found" message in response to the URL you requested.